# Can I have a joint distribution between a random discrete and a random continuous variable?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Can I have a joint distribution between a random discrete X and a random continuous variable Y?

Comment: You sure can. No rule against that.

Comment: Let, X be {1,2,3,4} , Y = [0, 10] (Y is continuous) then P(2.5,5.78) = 0 X=2.5 Y=5.78?

Comment: Well yes, that's how ordered pairs work. If you have a specific question, please edit your original post.

Comment: You can though the joint distribution will neither have a probability density function nor have a probability mass function.  It will have a cumulative distribution function

Answer (score 0):

Of course. If nothing else just take your favorite discrete random variable with CDF $P(N\le n) = F_N(n)$ and your favorite continuous random variable with CDF $P(X\le x) =F_X(x)$ and consider them to be independent. There's a joint distribution: $P(X\le x, N\le n) = F_X(x)F_N(n)$

Another common (but by no means exhaustive) example is a Gaussian mixture model where you flip a coin and if it comes up heads draw the RV $X$ from a $N(\mu_1,\sigma^2)$ distribution and if it's tails, draw it from a $N(\mu_2,\sigma).$ As you might imagine, the distribution of $X$ is continuous and generally looks bimodal.

In this model, the conditional distribution of $X$ given the value of the coinflip is Gaussian (with a mean depending on the outcome of the coinflip). This translates to a joint distribution between the coinflip (discrete RV) and $X$ (continuous).

This kind of pattern is common, where a parameter of a continuous distribution is chosen conditional on a discrete RV.